# libcamera-hello: how to know the actual device used?

Tags: camera, libcamera

libcamera-hello: how to know the actual device used?

The `--list-camera` option gives:

```
$ libcamera-hello --list-camera
Available cameras
-----------------
0 : imxXYZ [wxh] (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imxXYZ@1a)
```

So you can select he camera with `--camera`:

```
$ libcamera-hello --camera 0
```

... But how to know the `/dev/video*` associated to `--camera 0`?

Ideally, is there a way to get the same result than `libcamera-hello` but with `v4l2-ctl` (specifying all options at command line)?